# How to get specific elements from Recycler View?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have Recycler View. I want to make searching for elements. I've created en EditText and I want to get the specific elements from Recycler View, but how can I do it? If I have all list elements from Recycler View in Activity below the EditText and I need to pull the specific elements out. What a method do I need to use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to do a search over recyclerview items you should to use make your adapter Filterable, and override it's method such as getFilter & setFilter
check this guide : [RecyclerView Search Filter](https://www.androidhive.info/2017/11/android-recyclerview-with-search-filter-functionality/)